# How to download a .tgz file from a webpage using shell command or wget?

Tags: shell, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, wget

I want to download the metadeta of Full dataset (v1.0) from this webpage- https://www.nuscenes.org/nuscenes#download but I can't. I saw the tutorial which downloads a minidata set and the command for that is-  `!wget https://www.nuscenes.org/data/v1.0-mini.tgz`. Although the webpage mentions that login is required, this command is able to download the mini data set file. Link to the [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit/blob/master/python-sdk/tutorials/nuscenes_tutorial.ipynb)

I tried to download the metadata by simply replacing the file name with v1.0-trainval_meta. I know that file name because I downloaded it by clicking on the link. I am using google colab with a GPU. I tried to google search and learn about !wget but none of my commands worked.
One of my attempt- `!wget https://www.nuscenes.org/nuscenes/data/v1.0-trainval_meta.tgz  # Download the metadata.`

I am getting this error after I download it and try to unzip it. This is obviously not the file I want because file size is too small-

```
--2021-10-27 20:59:39--  https://www.nuscenes.org/download/v1.0-trainval_meta.tgz
Resolving www.nuscenes.org (www.nuscenes.org)... 52.222.158.101, 52.222.158.97, 52.222.158.48, ...
Connecting to www.nuscenes.org (www.nuscenes.org)|52.222.158.101|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6006 (5.9K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘v1.0-trainval_meta.tgz’

v1.0-trainval_meta. 100%[===================>]   5.87K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-10-27 20:59:39 (27.3 MB/s) - ‘v1.0-trainval_meta.tgz’ saved [6006/6006]


gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Your help would mean a lot. I am trying to run YOLOv3 on nuscenes dataset.

Comment: So what have you downloaded? So inspect the file. It seems the link you posted is protected by some login stuff. You have to make your wget "login" to that site - consult the writer of that web page for an API token, if not, download it manually.

Comment: @KamilCuk I inspected the file. But instead of downloading the files on windows and then uploading it into VM is a going to waste a lot of time. I want to download the required files from the above mentioned website directly into a VM or Google Colab. Is that possible?